# Why use a Lambda-notation instead of normal notation

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, computer-science, lambda-calculus

We're learning a subset of Racket for a class. The book accompanying the class always uses lambda's inside (define f (lambda () E)) instead of (define f E).

Is there a good reason why? It doesn't seem that it's really necessary to have an anonymous function inside.

```
(define plus-one (+ 0 1)) 
(define plus-one-l (lambda () (+ 0 1)))
```

The first returns after calling plus-one 1 and the other says it's a procedure and using () around it also returns 1.

But why would you prefer the procedure over just having the value?

Answer (score 3):

## Why use a lambda?

To answer the question in your title, we would use a lambda because we want a procedure, or a function, instead of the value. This is the way in which Racket defines functions.

As you've identified, the first line assigns the value of 1 to `plus-one`, whereas the second line assigns the procedure of adding 0 to 1 to `plus-one-l`.

## Why would you prefer the procedure over just having the value?

This is a bad example of it, because this procedure will always return the same value, but imagine we want a function to add one to any number. Well then we would have something like this:

```lisp
(define plus-one-n (lambda (n) (+ n 1)))
```

Now we can call `(plus-one-n 3)` to get `4`, or `(plus-one-n 1336)` to get `1337`.

Procedures without any parameters are useful if we find ourselves repeating the same code in various places. If we need to add one to zero a lot of times, we can group that code into a procedure, and then just call it. If we then need to change all of that code, we need only change the body of the procedure. So if our requirements change such that we now want to add two to zero, we only have to change the body of the procedure (although we'd probably also want to change the name in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To delay evaluation.

A lambda without arguments is called a "thunk". Thunks are useful for:

1. Infinite lazy streams:

```
(define-syntax-rule (cons-stream x y)
  (cons x (lambda () y)))

(define ones (cons-stream 1 ones))
```

2. Functions as objects:

```
(define (f x)
  (lambda () x))

(define a (f 2))

(a) ; -->  2
```